# Change array head pointer C++

Tags: c++

let's say I have an array:

```
int* arr = new int[10];
```

and I want to get rid of the first cell in the array in **O(1)** complexity
so I thought maybe there is some way to change the array head pointer 
I mean :

```
arr = arr + 1 ;
```

**but this not solve the problem** the program still treats arr to the second cell(I can't realloc with this pointer ) instead of the memory block, array head 
So I'd love if someone can help me with that (to rid of the first cell in the array in O(1) complexity or change the array head pointer [I heard you could add asm code to the cpp code, could help ?] )

Comment: other than copying into a new array `arr = arr + 1` is the right thing to do (as long as you make sure you `delete` the original pointer not the modified one)

Comment: If you mean you still want to have 10 elements of space afterwards then you either have to allocate more to begin with  and then move the pointer, or you have to copy data.

Comment: How big of an array are you going to be doing this on?  If it is small enough, just use a vector and actually erase the element.  Cache is really, *really* fast.

Comment: "the program still treats arr to the second cell instead of the memory block, array head" This part is not clear

Comment: *"I have an array"* - you have a pointer to the first element of the array. `arr = arr + 1 ;` will advance pointer by one item so it will point to the second element of the array. *"the program still treats arr to the second cell instead of the memory block, array head"* - I have no idea what this is supposed to mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays always have constant number of elements throughout their lifetime. It is not possible to add or remove elements.

> I thought maybe there is some way to change the array head pointer I mean :
>
> ```
> arr = arr + 1 ;
> ```

Using a "head" pointer like this is the only (although, index based analogous solution is also possible) O(1) way to "remove" - or rather, pretend that elements have been removed from the array.

You shouldn't change `arr` itself though, since you need the original value to release the allocation.

> but this not solve the problem the program still treats arr to the second cell instead of the memory block, array head

It is really unclear why you think the problem wasn't solved.

Comment: Look I want to make array implementation of queue  
`
 int size;
 int maxSize;
 int* thisQueue;
`
and in case of dequeue I and to get rid of the arr[0] and start the arr for arr[1] to arr[9]
according to what I learn about array he have an head and I want to shift him

Comment: @EyalElbaz The "pointer to head" is a good approach for this purpose. Just keep the head pointer and the allocation pointer separate. Also, use `std::unique_ptr` for the latter.

Comment: and if I cant do this maybe  to free all the array and allocate the new array in arr+1 to arr+9

Comment: @EyalElbaz You can do that. But that's going to be expensive. Reallocation will be relatively expensive for small arrays, and the linear copying of all minus one elements is expensive for large arrays.